# Trying to get property of non-object on codeigniter when check data

Tags: codeigniter, where-clause

I would like to show data from database with "where" condition, how to show data in controller, the error show is "**Trying to get property of non-object**"

here is my controller  :

```
 $checkpassword          = $this->m_user->checkpassword($oldpassword);
        if($this->input->post('oldpassword') != $checkpassword->password)
        {
            $data['inputerror'][]   = 'oldpassword';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'your old password is wrong';
            $data['status']         = FALSE;
        }
```

and here is my model :

```
  function checkpassword($oldpassword)
    {
        $this->db->where('password',$oldpassword);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->row();
    }
```

Comment: where is error?

Comment: @pradeep I was edit

Comment: What was the results of `print_r($checkpassword)` ?

Comment: where u define $oldpassword, pls more details

Comment: @MuhammadUsman is all field of user table

Comment: @pradeep old password is form input  on modals

Comment: What is the "non-object"? Please show entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform `row()` or `result()` (any type of result object) and you get no results e.g. empty array or stdClass object you cannot access any of the properties because it is empty. That is why it is critical to build in `num_rows()`.

```
function checkpassword($oldpassword)
    {
        $this->db->where('password',$oldpassword);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table)
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
if (is_null($checkpassword) || $this->input->post('oldpassword') != $checkpassword->password) { ... }
```

---

Now I have two problems with your code:

1. It appears that you are storing plaintext passwords (a big no no)
2. You check the password on the basis of the entire user table as per a comment you stated above but it is *still* possible that two users have the same password and thus you should also include a `$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'))` in you check password function.

Given these two remarks it seems like your understanding of authentication systems is rather rudimentary (I don't mean to say this to be rude), and maybe you should consider using a pre-built plugin like [Ion Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth), I use it myself and can recommend it.